# making a takeUntil function in haskell

Tags: haskell, take

I want make a function which when given a string eg "ab" and "cdabd" when it will be used on these two strings it will output "cd"

I have this  up to now

```
takeUntil :: String -> String -> String
takeUntil [] [] = []
takeUntil xs [] = []
takeUntil [] ys = []
takeUntil xs ys = if contains xs ys then -- ???? I get stuck here.
```

the contains function is one in which I had defined previously(this whole function should be case insensitive)
contains function:

```
contains :: String -> String -> Bool
contains _ [] = True
contains [] _ = False
contains xs ys = isPrefixOf (map toLower ys) (map toLower xs) || contains (tail(map toLower xs)      (map toLower ys)
```

Comment: Your definition is a bit wrong, did you mean `takeUntil` on the last 4 lines?

Comment: yes I did. it should be takeUntil

Comment: Also, it'd be really helpful if you could post the code for `contains`, or at least the type signature and a more specific description of what it does.

Comment: Im guessing that I may be needing a helper function to define what should happen if xs is in ys. the helper function should cut off everything before the two strings are matched i.e. "ab" "cdab" = "cd"

Comment: There are a lot of ways to solve this problem, but I think using `contains` will make things difficult.  For one thing, what if I passed in `takeUntil "ab" "abcdab"`?  Using `contains`, this would return `""` instead of `"cdab"`.  Using `isPrefixOf` directly would be a better choice as @JosEdu has done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to do this, but continuing with your path, try the following:

```
import Data.List

takeUntil :: String -> String -> String
takeUntil [] [] = []                           --don't need this
takeUntil xs [] = [] 
takeUntil [] ys = [] 
takeUntil xs (y:ys) = if   isPrefixOf xs (y:ys)
                      then []
                      else y:(takeUntil xs (tail (y:ys)))
```

Some outputs:

```
takeUntil "ab" "cdabd"
"cd"

takeUntil "b" "cdabd"
"cda"

takeUntil "d" "cdabd"
"c"

takeUntil "c" "cdabd"
""

takeUntil "xxx" "cdabd"
"cdabd"
```

**EDIT:**

The OP wants the function to be case-insensitive.

Well, again you can do that in lot of ways. For example you can write a `lowerCase` function like (i think you already have it in `Data.Text`):

```
import qualified Data.Char as Char

lowerCase :: String -> String
lowerCase [] = []
lowerCase (x:xs) = (Char.toLower x):(lowerCase xs)
```

And then use it like (maybe ugly and not very practical):

```
takeUntil (lowerCase "cd") (lowerCase "abcDe")
"ab"
```

That is the result you expect.

Also, you can use that `lowerCase` function inside `takeUntil`:

```
-- ...
takeUntil xs (y:ys) = if  isPrefixOf (lowerCase xs) (lowerCase (y:ys))
-- ...
```

So, you can just do:

```
takeUntil "cd" "abcDe"
"ab"
```

Anyway, i think the best option is that one @bheklilr suggested. Make your own `isPrefixOfCaseless` function.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou but the thing is I need to make it case insensitive so that if "cd" "abcDe" it will stil give me "ab"

Comment: try using `toLower` from `Data.Char` on both the `xs` and `y`

Comment: The first case of `takeUntil` is subsumed by the second, hence it can be removed. Also, `tail (y:ys)` can be simplified to just `ys`.

Comment: @Nicholas If you want to perform this check without case sensitivity, I'd suggest making a `isPrefixOfCaseless` (shorter name than `isPrefixOfCaseInsensitive`) function that locally maps `toLower` over its arguments.  You'll end up duplicating some operations, but in this case it's better to get it working rather than getting it to run as fast as possible.

Comment: Right, `caselessPrefixOf pre list = isPrefixOf (map toLower pre) (map toLower list)` is going to be valuable. You can use other functions from Data.List too; `takeUntil xs ys = maybe ys fst $ find (isPrefixOf xs . snd) $ zip (inits ys) (tails ys)` brings it down to a one-liner with convoluted logic and you can just swap in `caselessPrefixOf` to that.

Comment: I like @bheklilr suggestion. Anyway i edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Within the numerous approaches to define `takeUntil`, consider using [Data.Text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.11.2.3/docs/Data-Text.html) functions as follows,

```
takeUntil :: String -> String -> String
takeUntil sep txt =  unpack $ fst $ breakOn (pack sep) (toCaseFold $ pack txt)
```

Note that `pack` converts a `String` to a `Text`, whereas `uncpak` does the inverse; `toCaseFold` for case insensitive operations; `breakOn` delivers a pair where the first element includes text until the first (possible) match.

**Update**

This approach covers tests already suggested, yet it does not preseve original `String` for instance here,

```
takeUntil "e" "abcDe"
"abcd"
```

A work around this involves for instance the splitting by index at the break point.